# call mxml from actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I am very new to Flex & Action script and here is my requirement:

There is one boolean flag in action script and if flag value is true then redirect to success.mxml page and if flag value false then redirect to error.mxml page.

Can anyone suggest me, how to redirect to mxml page/componenet from action script based on some condition.

Answer (score 0):

MXML files are Actionscript class files. They are not pages as in JSP.

Although you can add both success.mxml and error.mxml as a child in Application tag and depending upon your flag value, you can set visibility of either to `true` or `false`.

Please Learn some Flex tutorial or book first because this question is too basic to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the two variable with data type of both the mxml.

so as you your flag is true, just create a new instance of that variable and you can also call its all the public variable/functions for you as file. You also call their layout objects if you given them id's.

It is not bound in the Flex. You can call anything form anywhere if not then try Events.

Try to learn the flex tutorial for that. You can also try the Tour de flex.

Regards,
Manish